# Swf restrictions

Tags: apache, tomcat, flash, cross-domain-policy

I have two swf (A and B) and inside A i am doing a urloader of B. It works fine. They are in the same directory.
Now what i want is to prevent everyone from accessing B (except A). I am using apache/tomcat server with https. 
This is my crossdomain file

```
<cross-domain-policy>
     <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Its like this because i also need to access some external ports.

its possible to protect B by crossdomain or directly in the server by configuring tomcat access rules?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to do a direct download of the swf B, so will be anyone. Cross domain policy file is simply something respected by flash.

If you want to prevent the download, I suggest you bring in a server side language in between.

Something like : `.../download.php?id=xyz` or `.../download.aspx?id=xyz`

There you may authenticate / validate the request for the swf.

Comment: thanks. The problem is that if i put something to authenticate it will know in flash A and therefore it can be copied to another flash.